# Save Word document in a different format without effective active document

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way in VB.net to save a Word document as a different format (i.e. Me.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs) without switching to it?  For example, if the current document is an unsaved, I want to save an copy of that document as HTML but still keep the unsaved document active.

Comment: Do you want to save a document that is not the ActiveDocument ? Or do you want to use the SaveAs feature on your active document ?

Comment: I want to save a copy of the ActiveDocument in the background, but not switch to the saved copy.  Default behavior for saveAs opens the saved document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the current doc variable to another variable and save it.

```
 Try
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document



        'Start Word and open the document template.
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Visible = True
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
        oDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(5.08)
        oDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(4.57)
            oDoc.PageSetup.RightMargin = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
            oDoc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(3.81)
            oDoc.PageSetup.PageHeight = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
            oDoc.PageSetup.PageWidth = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(21)

            'TIll Above your entire odoc is formatted
            'From below I will save it to my own code

            Dim newdoc As Word.Document
            newdoc = oDoc
            newdoc.SaveAs2("d:\file.pdf", Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)

            'All done. Close this form.
            'BSPGlobals.DataBase.Contact.ExitApp()
            MessageBox.Show("Print to Doc Done.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error at Printing the bill." & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        End Try
```